# Policies for maintaining access credentials on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, security, keys

Managing EC2 access keys and X.509 certificates can become challenging when you start to deal with large numbers of instances.  Do any EC2 users here have good policies and/or tools for:

- rotating EC2 access keys and X.509 certificates
- preventing copies of keys / certs
  from proliferating onto instances and AMIs
- keeping the keys in a centralized
  location with the appropriate access
  ?

Comment: I've never used it but RSA has a certficate manager product of which I am aware.  Venafi is another product vendor and there is also Comodo.  But then you are probably aware of these companies and their products.

I am certain there are others out there with similar issues and will be curious to see what kind of answers you get.

Comment: is this for windows or linux primarily?  Client and server that is...

Comment: Mostly Linux, but it would be nice to have a cross-platform solution.

Comment: If you aren't using IAM already, that's a very important first step. If you are using EC2 access keys for SSH, I recommend not doing so; use them for deployment only, long enough for your deployment process to install vanilla SSH keys.

Answer (score 1):

I created a script to manage multiple AWS accounts (tested on Mac and Linux): https://github.com/thalweg/aws-account